# Squat development

Tags: weightlifting, powerlifting

I'm focusing on powerlifting and weightlifting. I am 59kg in weight. I am currently able to deadlift 170kg for 1RM and 120kg for 1RM. As you can see, there is a very big difference between the two lifts. Is there a way I can make my squat 1RM catch up with my deadlift 1RM?

Comment: You are comparing apples with oranges here. Making two numbers that shouldn't be equal the same leads you nowhere. Is your squat not developing the way you want? An issue that could be fixed perhaps. Could be form, could be your program, could be anything. Low bar or high bar? I believe most can move more weight with #1. Maybe nutrition, 59kg is very low for the average man - unless you are not the average man, hard to tell from your question. Please include more information and perhaps take a guess what keeps you from squatting more?

Comment: I originally nominated https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/40302/squat-progress-and-development/40308#40308 as a duplicate of this question but now the newer question has received an answer, so this question should now probably be marked as a duplicate of that instead.