# Squat Progress and Development

Tags: weightlifting, powerlifting

I'm focusing on powerlifting and weightlifting. I am 59kg in weight. I am currently able to deadlift 170kg for 1RM and squat 120kg for 1RM. As you can see, there is a very big difference between the two lifts. Is there a way I can make my squat 1RM catch up with my deadlift 1RM?

While I have been able to add 2kg every fortnight to squats, I've been able to go from 160kg to 170kg in one week for the deadlift. I use low bar for deadlift. Why there is so much disparity between progress rate of the two lifts? I have been doing [agonist-antagonist training using Arnold's program as my template](https://www.t-nation.com/workouts/arnolds-agonist-antagonist-training) for a year. However, I modified the program to 1-5 per set. Just that for some lifts, progress is slower than others.

For nutrition, I eat 12 eggs a day evenly spaced out in the day. I also eat 120g of protein from meat, beans, etc. I take coffee before every workout. Plenty of fruits of course, as well as wholemeal carbohydrates. Been using this diet for the past two years with no complications whatsoever.

My overall question is how can I make my progress for squat improve with the information I have given concerning my routine, diet and progress?

Comment: Apparent duplicate of https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/40300/squat-development/40301#40301 by the same user.

Comment: It would probably be better to edit your original question with the additional information than create a new question like this, replying to a comment that appears in a different place.

Comment: I have made a major edit that trims down the question to the relevant points. I also copied over the original question that tripleee linked to. (In linked question, tripleee also commented that the original should maybe flagged as duplicate as this question has an answer.)

Comment: Here's Raditz_35's original comment on linked question: You are comparing apples with oranges here. Making two numbers that shouldn't be equal the same leads you nowhere. Is your squat not developing the way you want? An issue that could be fixed perhaps. Could be form, could be your program, could be anything. Low bar or high bar? I believe most can move more weight with #1. Maybe nutrition, 59kg is very low for the average man - unless you are not the average man, hard to tell from your question. Please include more information and perhaps take a guess what keeps you from squatting more?

Comment: Almost 3 x bodyweight deadlift! Damn you are strong.

Comment: Hello @Andy. Actually in the video, it's 180kg. The initial 170kg was at the time I typed my question. The video was much later, I'd say a week. Therefore my new 1RM for deadlift is 180kg. So therefore more than 3x bodyweight

Answer (score 1):

This question is somewhat confusing to me. I'm guessing you're wondering why your deadlift is far better than your squat?

In a nut shell this is normal. Some people are better at deadlifts, some people are better at squats, some people have crazy bench press in comparison to their squat/deadlift. It's largely based on body poroprtions and genetics etc. To give a personal example my best squat and deadlift are both 200kg, however my training partners best squat is 160kg and his best deadlift is 230kg. It would be ridiculous to assume that i should be deadlifting 270kg or that he should be squatting 230kg, and that the only reason we aren't is because we don't train them well enough.

You could try an actual strength program if that is your goal. something like 5x5 stronglifts/starting strength/5 3 1. I personally used jonnie canditos linear program for a while. There are plenty out there.

I recommend filming your squats and watching plenty of technique vidoes from people who are actually strong. This will help improve/reinforce your knowledge of squatting and you should hopefully learn some more advanced techniques from said videos.

As you mentiond your deadlift is strong relative to your squat i'd say you have a strong back and weak legs, but without seeing you train i wouldn't really be able to tell. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU2gjpPcs_Y) will help.

Good luck squatting.

Comment: OK. Much appreciated for your contribution. I'll make a video of that session then send it to this platform. Hopefully it will suffice to a preferable diagnostic. Looking forward to being elite like u guys

Comment: I posted the video via YouTube for this weeks deadlift session. Here's the link https://youtu.be/d1Z-RYAgL58